# Sass preform a function on a list of variables

Tags: list, function, sass

I have set up variables for the colors that i want to work with, say:

```
$navy:           #001F3F;
$blue:           #0074D9;
$aqua:           #7FDBFF;
$teal:           #39CCCC;
```

Is there any way of defining a list like i did below, and then use functions on all variables in that list.

```
$colors:
  ($navy)($blue)($aqua)($teal);
```

I.e. darken all colors at once and put them inside a new list by doing something like?

```
$colors-dark:
  @each $color in $colors {
    $#{$color}-dark: darken($color, 10);
  };
```

And will i then be able to, whenever i have an element i.e. a button that I might want to have a subclass for each color as a backgound option:

```
@each $color in $colors-dark {
  .btn.#{$color} {
    backgound-color:$color;
  }
}
```

Would be such a time saver instead of the darken or lighten all colors one at a time.

Sorry if my question is poorly written, i just started getting into sass after years of plain css, and i'm still kind of unsure how sass work along with its limitations.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define a list with an `@each` or create a new list/variable `name` with interpolation.

You `can` create map `values` with interpolation and get your desired outcome.

[DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/f7511a1fd5d4e2b05d4d8e2864c6481d)

```
// Put your colors in a map.
$colors: (
  navy: #001F3F,
  blue: #0074D9,
  aqua: #7FDBFF,
  teal: #39CCCC
);

// Create some empty global maps
$colors-dark: ();
$colors-light: ();

@each $key, $color in $colors {
  // Make new maps for each iteration
  $dark: (#{$key}-dark: darken($color, 10%));
  $light: (#{$key}-light: lighten($color, 10%));

  // Update global map with iteration map
  $colors-dark: map-merge($colors-dark, $dark);
  $colors-light: map-merge($colors-light, $light);
};

// Dark colors
@each $key, $color in $colors-dark {
  .btn.#{$key} {
    backgound-color: $color;
  }
}

// Light colors
@each $key, $color in $colors-light {
  .btn.#{$key} {
    backgound-color: $color;
  }
}
```